# Sheets - turn string of letters into a string that contains a count of each letter

Tags: google-sheets, substring, equation

I've been working on a complicated project in google sheets:
I have a 10x10 box, in which each cell can be 1 of 6 things: `A, B, C, D, E, empty`

Any given row or column (single row/column input is very important to the purpose of the formula) should return a string of numbers that is 6 digits, with the first digit signifying the count of `A` and the last digit signifying the count of `empty`.

So if one of the rows contains `|D| |D|D|C|A| |C|B| |` it should return: `112303`.

The closest component I had working/was happy with was:
`(concatenate(transpose(sort(transpose(A1:AJ),1,true))))`

this formula returns `abccddd` when using the example above as input

I worked with a lot of different functions and only got it to output numbers to a degree; everything I tried didn't produce the desired result and/or was extremely clunky, long, ridiculous and un-maintainable.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: If this is google sheets why the excel and vba tags?

Answer (score 1):

Use countif()

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(COUNTIF(A1:J1,{"A","B","C","D","E",""})))
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing thank you so much!
Of course, it was much simpler than I initially thought.